# A mystery involving putStrLn

Tags: haskell, syntax-error, io-monad, do-notation

Why does the piece of code below produce the error `parse error on input ‘putStrLn’`?

```
main = do line <- fmap reverse getLine
   putStrLn $ "You said " ++ line ++ " backwards!"
   putStrLn $ "Yes, you said " ++ line ++ " backwards!"

<interactive>:11:4: error: parse error on input ‘putStrLn’
```

Also, why does the following piece of code produce the error `parse error on input ‘let’`?

```
main = do line <- getLine
  let line' = reverse line
  putStrLn $ "You said " ++ line' ++ " backwards!"
  putStrLn $ "Yes, you said " ++ line' ++ " backwards!"


 <interactive>:31:4: error: parse error on input ‘let’
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Both snippets have the same problem. If you put the first action of a `do` block on the same line as the `do` itself, you still have to indent the rest of the actions in the `do` block as far as the first one. Two choices to fix it:

```
main = do line <- fmap reverse getLine
          putStrLn $ "You said " ++ line ++ " backwards!"
          putStrLn $ "Yes, you said " ++ line ++ " backwards!"
```

or

```
main = do
   line <- fmap reverse getLine
   putStrLn $ "You said " ++ line ++ " backwards!"
   putStrLn $ "Yes, you said " ++ line ++ " backwards!"
```

Comment: It occurred to me that indentation might be the issue, and then I saw your answer. Unfortunately in the book I am using to learn Haskell, the necessity of this particular type of indentation is not mentioned, so it's good to know. :)

Answer (score 3):

It also works when explicit separators are used throughout:

```
main = do { line <- fmap reverse getLine ;
   putStrLn $ "You said " ++ line ++ " backwards!" ;
   putStrLn $ "Yes, you said " ++ line ++ " backwards!" }

main = do { line <- getLine ;
   let { line' = reverse line } ;                     -- NB let's { }s
   putStrLn $ "You said " ++ line' ++ " backwards!" ;
   putStrLn $ "Yes, you said " ++ line' ++ " backwards!" }
```

This is not a substitute for the good indentation style, but an addition to it.